# Julia: import contents from package in same directory

Tags: import, julia

Suppose I have a file, stuff.jl, that includes the following function:

```
function foo(x)
    return x
end
```

How do I call foo within the Julia interpreter from the **same directory** containing stuff.jl?

Comment: aware of the following: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Modules_and_packages... error arises in calling >> import stuff as would be done in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[include](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.MainInclude.include) will load and eval the file (not a [module](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/)) into the context of the REPL :

```
julia> include("stuff.jl")
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(10)
10
```

And even if the file is not on the same directory, you could load it passing it's `path` as a parameter:

```
julia> include("test\\stuff.jl");

julia> foo(20)
20
```

<sub>tested with `Julia Version 0.4.3`</sub>